# Python subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['tar', '-xf', '/home//filename.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I am trying to extract contents of a .tar.gz file via a python script submit. my code is

```
#extract archive file contents in home directory#
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['tar','-xf','filename.tar.gz'])
```

This is extracting the file in the desired location but also returning me error `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['tar', '-xf', '/home//filename.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 2` because of which my script stops running. Any help would be greatly appreciatd.
Thanks,
vsg

Comment: I'd recommend to run command tar -xf  /home//filename.tar.gz from shell then to check exit code typing echo $?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg on running the tar command in shell, the error msg is `gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

Comment: @YuriGinsburg when I run 'echo $?', I get the number `2` in return which I believe is the same as the original error

Comment: So  the problem is with the archive. It is always good to check the exit code of external program and print process; stderr in case of abnormal termination.

Comment: @yuriginsburg I rearchived and then tried the same process again but this time recvd error 'exist status 1'.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing the following :

1. removing all special characters from the name of my to be archived csv file and the tar file name.
2. rearchiving using the same above command